# Google Cloud Storage - Handle rotating keys from outside the environment

Tags: rotation, google-cloud-storage, key

Need a help on how do I handle rotating keys on google cloud storage thats managed by one google account but being accessed by an app thats running on another google cloud account.  I tried searching for solutions but couldn't find an answer

Comment: Can you explain what must be rotate? What is the current process? What is the challenge?

Comment: Storage access keys are to be rotated: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/key-rotation

and how do i access the rotated keys from another google account?

Answer (score 1):

With IAM service you can grant permission at project level, and, for some resources, at resources level.

It's the case for your KMS keys where you can grant permission on the key rings

[image]

Or directly at the key level

[image]

Choose what works the best for your use case, and grant the service account of the external project with the correct permission (decrypter to read the files in the GCS, encryter to write files)

*Note: A key rotation is a new version of a key.*